# Assign results from a Solve to variables

Tags: equation-solving

Great day to all of you; how can I assign the results in the attached picture, which is obtained from a Solve command, to variables? i.e. I need the values of c[-3,-3], c[-3,-2], ...[image]

Comment: Look up Replace in the help.

Comment: @JonathanShock, I tried to use Replace, but it does not work. Is it possible to send the file to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to retrieve the values? E.g.,

```
vars = Catenate@Array[c, {6, 6}, {-3, -3}]  (* your "variables" *)
rules = Thread[Rule[vars, RandomReal[{0, 1}, 36]]] (* example rules *)
vars /. rules  (* retrieve values *)
```

Or did you want to make some kinds of assignments? (If so, which?) For example, if you really (are you sure?) need all those rules to become assignments, you could

```
rules /. {Rule -> Set}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The second part is what I am looking for.